# Choosing proper resistor for battery powered led lamp

Tags: led, resistors

Noob alert, I only know some basics of EE that have proven to be insufficient

I bought a stylish lamp which I really like, but it's electrical parts were clearly designed by someone who did not know what he's doing. It has a strip of 60 12V LEDs and slot for 9V 6F22 battery, nothing more. Running 9V over 12V LEDs make them a bit dimm, and after a few hours the battery voltage dropped making them even dimmer.

I bought a step up converter to boost the voltage to 12V and those LEDs shined much brighter, as they should. The battery however got hot and after about an hour it was drained. If I got it right there is not enough resistance in the circuit and I basically shorted the battery through those poor LEDs.

I replaced the battery and found a 10 ohm resistor (only one I could find). I thought when connected in series with LEDs it would limit the current draw 10 times (short battery currently is about 7.5A), but instead I got a fresh burn mark on my fingers. Clearly my understanding of electrical circuits is not correct.

Am I right in my assumption that I need a resistor in series with the LED stripe to reduce current draw?
How should I choose the value of the resistor? Are there any important parameters other than resistance I need to pay attention to?
Is it even possible or feasible to expect such setup to work?

Comment: What was the power rating of the resistor you used?

Comment: Why do you say the lamp was originally designed by someone who did not know what he was doing? It clearly did work and did not heat up the battery or burn fingers, it was likely specially engineered to just work. It is also unknown what circuitry the lamp or the LED strip has. Maybe there is a converter or resistances somewhere. How do you know if those are 12V LEDs?

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a bigger battery. Since you are driving the strip harder (applying a higher voltage) you also need to be sure you don't overheat the strip.

Comment: There is no way to make the strip brighter and maintain the same battery life you had before. Making the strip brighter is going to cost you in battery life. You may be able to compromise between the two by fine-tuning your boost converter output voltage (if it is adjustable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The battery however got hot and after about an hour it was drained. If I got it right there is not enough resistance in the circuit and I basically shorted the battery through those poor LEDs.

It's not really about the amount of resistance.  A small 9V battery simply can't produce very much current.  Try to draw too much and it overheats and runs flat very quickly.

It only worked as originally designed because the LEDs were being run at a current well below the maximum that they could handle, and this put less load on the battery.

Adding the 12V boost converter and then the resistor boosted the voltage, but then cut it again by droppig voltage in the resistor.  This wasted power by making the resistor hot.

The designers did know what they were doing - producing a cheap light that isn't very bright, but runs for a reasonable time on a really under-sized battery.